# Is the following sufficient to determine (not prove) that $a_n=\frac{sin(n^2\pi)}{n^2+4}$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

For the following sequences, determine whether they converge, diverge or oscillate
using the relevant convergence tests. If they converge, state their limit. DO NOT try
to prove these limits.

The question was:

$$a_n=\frac{sin(n^2\pi)}{n^2+4}$$

The way I went about solving it was saying $-1\le sin(n^2\pi)\le 1$ and that $n^2+4>1$ and therefore as n $\rightarrow \infty\ ,a_n\rightarrow 0,$ as $n^2+4>sin(n^2\pi)$. The sequence converges

Is this sufficient?

Comment: One should also note that $n^2+4 \to \infty $ for $n \to \infty$ because just saying that $n^2+4 > \sin(n^2 \pi)$ is not sufficient as $2>1$ does not imply that $a_n = \frac{1}{2}$ converges to zero (I know that this is a stupid example, but just to illustrate my point it should be fine). Even easier in this case: $\sin(n^2 \pi) = 0$ for all $n$ because the sine of a multiple of $\pi$ is always zero

Comment: The easiest way to immediately see the answer is to explicitly compute $a_{(100)}$ and $a_{(101)}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

In fact, you noticed that
$$ \frac{-1}{n²+4} ≤ a_n ≤ \frac{1}{n²+4} . $$
Moreover, we know that
$$ \lim_{n → \infty} \frac{-1}{n²+4} = 0 ,$$
$$ \lim_{n → \infty} \frac{1}{n²+4} = 0 .$$

So we can apply the theorem and say that
$$ \lim_{n → \infty} a_n = 0 .$$

Comment: I should have noticed this, I have only recently just started studying real analysis so I do not notice what I need to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you did only leads to the conclusion that $|a_n| < 1$. However, this is not enough to say the limit exists. Consider the example $$a_n = \frac{1}{2}\sin n \ \ (\forall n\in \mathbb N)$$ where we again have $a_n < 1$ but the limit does not exist.

---

For your question, note that
$$-\frac{1}{n^2+4} \le \frac{\sin(\pi n^2)}{n^2+4} \le \frac{1}{n^2+4}$$
Now, remember the Sandwich (or Squeeze or Two Policemen) theorem.